# Запустить js функцию из другого файла

Tags: php, javascript

При нажатии на кнопку аяксом подгружается файл на странице, в котором также лежит js код (он генерируется относительно того какие данные идут из БД, поэтому сразу вывести скрипт наружу не получится.) 
При нажатии на определенную клавишу, необходимо запустить этот скрипт. Я ее завернул в функцию. 
Но консоль говорит, что

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mapsss is not defined
```

Comment: [всё работает](http://plnkr.co/edit/yI372ZMKmVrGUpQEUzRl?p=preview)

только это плохая идея так делать, лучше на запрос возвращайте json, который подставляйте в уже загруженную функцию.

Answer (score 1):

возможно вы не подключили файл или не правильно указали путь к тому файлу в котором у вас прописана инструкция для обработки нажатия клавиши

Comment: а как я подключу файл, если его еще нет? он подгрузится аяксом только после нажатия на клавишу.